# Display total sum of values when selecting them

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I have an list with values which is generated by an database query.
I want to see the total sum of values that been selected (by an checkbox) by the user.

[image]

Code for checkbox:

```
<?php
$i = -1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$i++;
?>
echo '<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="bedrag_optellen(this, <?php echo $i ?>);" value= "'.$row['bedrag_incl'].'"></td>
<td>&euro; '.number_format($row['bedrag_incl'], 2, ',', ' ').'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
}
?>
```

Code for output field:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="51"><input type="text" id="bedragen_selected" name="bedragen_selected" value="" size="10" style="text-align:right;background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript"</script>
function bedrag_optellen(checkbox, nr)
{
        var i, totaal = 0;
        var elems = document.getElementsByName('bedrag_optellen[]');
        var l = elems.length;
        for(i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
            if(formElement['bedrag_optellen[]'][i].checked = true)
            {
                 totaal += parseFloat(elems[i].value) || 0;
             }

            document.getElementById('bedragen_selected').value = totaal.toFixed( 2 );
        }
}
</script>
```

The code is not working, also there is no error given.

Is there anyone to help me out?

https://jsfiddle.net/fawavmbo/

Comment: can you add a demo/fiddle ?

Comment: What is `formElement`? Why aren't you doing `elems[i]` instead of `formElement['bedrag_optellen[]'][i]`?

Comment: one misstake is there: `formElement['bedrag_optellen[]'][i].checked = true` - you are not comparing, but setting. has to be `==`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fawavmbo/

Comment: </script>. Closing script tag before the content of javascipt

Comment: You're passing `nr` as the second argument to `bedrag_optellen()` but you're not using it there.

Comment: Try with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fawavmbo/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fawavmbo/2/).

I have used jQuery for the simplicity it provides.

I made the following changes:

1. Added a class `cost` to the checkboxes.
2. Removed the `onClick` attribute.
3. Added jQuery.

For the code to work in you system, add the code below to your `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the snippet.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input class='cost' type="checkbox" value= "8"></td>
    <td>&euro; 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='cost' type="checkbox"  value= "3"></td>
    <td>&euro; 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='cost' type="checkbox" value= "19"></td>
    <td>&euro; 19</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='cost' type="checkbox" value= "2"></td>
    <td>&euro; 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='cost' type="checkbox" value= "15"></td>
    <td>&euro; 15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='cost' type="checkbox" value= "12"></td>
    <td>&euro; 12</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td width="51"><input type="text" id="bedragen_selected" name="bedragen_selected" value="" size="10" style="text-align:right;background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var sum = 0;

$('.cost').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        sum = sum + parseInt($(this).val());
    } else {
        sum = sum - parseInt($(this).val());
    }
    $('#bedragen_selected').val(sum);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Shrinivas. Your code seems not to be working when I copy it to my system.

Comment: You need to add the jquery library to your `<head>`. Updated the answer.

Comment: I am using other scripts so that will not be the problem since the jquery library is already present.

Comment: Then the code should work. It is working on my system as well as on jsfiddle. What problem are you facing on you system?

Comment: Still have the same problem, not getting it to work, but also no errors.

Comment: I have changed
$('.cost').click(function() {
to
$('.cost').live('click',function(){
That seems to work.

But I am not seeing an value like € 624,12 but like € 624

Comment: I used parseFloat() instead of parseInt() for the decimals.